# Using CFDocumentItem within the fix for the CFDocument issue ignoring background colour when in loop

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I've got a `cfdocument` issue arising from [a bug that's been there for at least 11 years](https://macromedia.coldfusion.cfml-general-discussion.narkive.com/gLNhE2BL/cfdocument-color-problems), that causes pdf files created within a loop to lose colour after the first file.

There's a fix for this as detailed in the previous 11 year old link, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617295/cfdocument-ignoring-background-color-when-in-loop), but that fix doesn't seem to work if you have a `cfdocumentitem` within it - like a header/footer. Using the fix with a header and footer I get the following error:

> Routines cannot be declared more than once.
>
> The routine _cffuncCFDOCUMENTITEM_cfpdf2ecfm9393969822 has been declared twice in different templates. ColdFusion cannot
>   determine the line of the template that caused this error. This is
>   often caused by an error in the exception handling subsystem.

If I remove the `cfdocumentitem` it's fine. The error says it been called by different templates, but it's only calling one template (but multiple times).

Anyone know of a fix for this?!

Comment: It would help us if you could include some of your code so we can see what you are doing. Best would be a small reproducible example that causes the error. [ask]